# analyzing .DSYM file using lldb

Tags: c, lldb, dsym

I wrote a simple c program that makes use of the `assert()` call. I'd like to analyze it using lldb.

OS in use: OS X Mavericks

Compiler used to compile: 
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix

The `-g` compiler option generated a `.DSYM` directory. I wanted to know how to how to analyze this core using lldb.

PS: I have compiled using the `-g` option (`clang -g test.c`)

Comment: It isn't the assert() call in the program that generates the .dsym directory,  but the -g 
compiler directive. For more on how the assert() call works, type 'man 3 assert' at the 
terminal prompt.

Comment: Okay, got it. My bad. I thought the assert() generated the .dsym

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start lldb and then execute the command

```
target create --core /cores/core.NNNN
```

where "/cores/core.NNNN" is your core file. A simple example:

```
$ lldb

(lldb) target create --core /cores/core.5884
Core file '/cores/core.5884' (x86_64) was loaded.
Process 0 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x0000, 0x00007fff8873c866 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8873c866 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10:
-> 0x7fff8873c866:  jae    0x7fff8873c870            ; __pthread_kill + 20
   0x7fff8873c868:  movq   %rax, %rdi
   0x7fff8873c86b:  jmpq   0x7fff88739175            ; cerror_nocancel
   0x7fff8873c870:  ret    

(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x0000, 0x00007fff8873c866 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8873c866 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff85de835c libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 92
    frame #2: 0x00007fff87554bba libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 125
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8751ea5f libsystem_c.dylib`__assert_rtn + 321
    frame #4: 0x000000010c867f59 a.out`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff53398c50) + 89 at prog.c:7
    frame #5: 0x00007fff872b65fd libdyld.dylib`start + 1

(lldb) frame select 4
frame #4: 0x000000010c867f59 a.out`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff53398c50) + 89 at prog.c:7
   4    int main(int argc, char **argv)
   5    {
   6        int i = 0;
-> 7        assert(i != 0);
   8        return 0;
   9    }
   10   

(lldb) p i
(int) $0 = 0
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. You mentioned "how to analyze this core using lldb", so this would be how to load and analyze a core file *after* your program crashed. - But I am not sure anymore if that is what you wanted, or if you just want to debug your program (as described in the other answer).

Comment: Just to show some shortcuts to Martin's answer, You can run lldb on your core file from the command line, `$ lldb -c /cores/core.5884` and when selecting frame 4 in his example, there's a very handy shortcut, `f 4` for this.  The same shortcut exists for `thread select` -- `t`.

Comment: @JasonMolenda: Thanks. "man lldb" on OS X does not show the "-c" option (but it *is* shown with "lldb --help").

Answer (score 0):

At the command prompt, in the same directory where you have the symbols directory, type

```
lldb program-name
```

then use the commands you want as in this official gdb to lldb command map:

[lldb-gdb](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html)

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you. I got a "a.out" after I compiled the program and when I ran the program I got the a.out.dSYM. Let me know the steps on how to do it. I had already referred to the http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html you shared.

Comment: a.out is the default name the compiler assign to your compiled program (you can use -o <prog-name> compiler option to choose a different name). a.out.dSYM is a directory where the compiler stores (after you've given it the -g directive) the symbols that lldb can read during the debug session. To start the debug session just type in the terminal the command (as indicated in the answer) and use the debugger in the way you want.